# How to, from one file, create multiple files extracting specific piece of info for each?

Tags: file, awk

I have a file (File_1.clustr) that I would like to turn into multiple files, using `>Cluster N` as the name for the new files, i.e. Cluster_N.txt, and extract the information from each ">" beneath `>Cluster N` stopping before `... *`. I'm not even sure where to begin with this, can anybody help?

**Input file:**

File_1.clustr

```
>Cluster 0
0   574aa, >GCA_000350365.1_Foc4_1.0_B2_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_39024-44226_26... *
>Cluster 1
0   401aa, >GCA_000260195.2_FO_II5_V1_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g6.t1... *
1   108aa, >GCA_000260195.2_FO_II5_V1_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_59093-64307_60... at 93.52%
2   401aa, >GCA_000350365.1_Foc4_1.0_B2_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g5.t1... at 100.00%
3   108aa, >GCA_000350365.1_Foc4_1.0_B2_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_16327-21541_28... at 93.52%
4   401aa, >GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g20.t1... at 99.75%
5   108aa, >GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_25103-30317_60... at 92.59%
6   401aa, >GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g13.t1... at 100.00%
7   108aa, >GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_2796127-2801341_60... at 93.52%
8   401aa, >GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58.genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g6.t1... at 100.00%
9   108aa, >GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58.genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_5739325-5744539_60... at 93.52%
>Cluster 2
0   373aa, >GCA_005930515.1_160527_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g6.t1... *
>Cluster 3
0   371aa, >GCA_000350365.1_Foc4_1.0_B2_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g2.t1... *
1   79aa, >GCA_000350365.1_Foc4_1.0_B2_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_26225-31435_21... at 98.73%
2   30aa, >GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_760-3765_21... at 100.00%
3   371aa, >GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g18.t1... at 99.73%
4   79aa, >GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_2897725-2902935_56... at 97.47%
5   371aa, >GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58.genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g13.t1... at 99.73%
6   79aa, >GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58.genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_5872866-5878075_56... at 97.47%
```

**Desired output files:**

Cluster_0.txt

```
GCA_000350365_1_Foc4_1_0_B2_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_39024-44226_26
```

Cluster_1.txt

```
GCA_000260195.2_FO_II5_V1_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g6.t1
GCA_000260195.2_FO_II5_V1_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_59093-64307_60
GCA_000350365.1_Foc4_1.0_B2_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g5.t1
GCA_000350365.1_Foc4_1.0_B2_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_16327-21541_28
GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g20.t1
GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_25103-30317_60
GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g13.t1
GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_2796127-2801341_60
GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58.genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g6.t1
GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58.genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_5739325-5744539_60
```

Cluster_2.txt

```
GCA_005930515.1_160527_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g6.t1
```

Cluster_3.txt

```
GCA_000350365.1_Foc4_1.0_B2_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g2.t1
GCA_000350365.1_Foc4_1.0_B2_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_26225-31435_21
GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_760-3765_21
GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g18.t1
GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_2897725-2902935_56
GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58.genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g13.t1
GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58.genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_5872866-5878075_56
```

This is what I tried, but it does not work because it changes the names within the output files:

I started by trying to separate the fields:

```
awk '{gsub(">","",$0); print;}' File_1.clustr) | awk '{gsub("aa,","aa\t",$0); print;}' | sed 's/\./_/g' | awk '{gsub("___","\t",$0); print;}'
```

Which produced this output:

```
Cluster 0
0   574aa    GCA_000350365_1_Foc4_1_0_B2_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_39024-44226_26   *
Cluster 1
0   401aa    GCA_000260195_2_FO_II5_V1_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_g6_t1  *
1   108aa    GCA_000260195_2_FO_II5_V1_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_59093-64307_60     at 93_52%
2   401aa    GCA_000350365_1_Foc4_1_0_B2_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_g5_t1    at 100_00%
3   108aa    GCA_000350365_1_Foc4_1_0_B2_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_16327-21541_28   at 93_52%
4   401aa    GCA_001696625_1_C1HIR_9889_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_g20_t1    at 99_75%
5   108aa    GCA_001696625_1_C1HIR_9889_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_25103-30317_60    at 92_59%
6   401aa    GCA_007994515_1_UK0001_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_g13_t1    at 100_00%
7   108aa    GCA_007994515_1_UK0001_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_2796127-2801341_60    at 93_52%
8   401aa    GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_g6_t1  at 100_00%
9   108aa    GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_5739325-5744539_60     at 93_52%
Cluster 2
0   373aa    GCA_005930515_1_160527_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_g6_t1     *
Cluster 3
0   371aa    GCA_000350365_1_Foc4_1_0_B2_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_g2_t1    *
1   79aa     GCA_000350365_1_Foc4_1_0_B2_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_26225-31435_21   at 98_73%
2   30aa     GCA_001696625_1_C1HIR_9889_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_760-3765_21   at 100_00%
3   371aa    GCA_007994515_1_UK0001_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_g18_t1    at 99_73%
4   79aa     GCA_007994515_1_UK0001_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_2897725-2902935_56    at 97_47%
5   371aa    GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_g13_t1     at 99_73%
6   79aa     GWHAASU00000000_FocTR4_58_genomic_fna_Candidate_Sequence_5872866-5878075_56     at 97_47%
```

I then copied and pasted this into Excel, and used `grep ">Cluster" > Cluster_list.txt` to create a new file listing the names of the new files. I then replaced the spaces for an underscore in the file Cluster_list.txt using `awk '{gsub(" ","_",$0); print;}'`. After, I used `for i in $(cat Cluster_list.txt); do touch ${i} ; done` to create files which follow the names of the clusters. I then opened each file using nano and pasted the corresponding GCA... into the file. This was very cumbersome, and once I had done it, I realised that initially using `sed 's/\./_/g' | awk '{gsub("___","\t",$0); print;}'` to create a tab-seperated file, replaced the "." in the GCA... section with "_", so the GCA... sections don't exactly match.

Surely there is a more efficient way to do it, so I won't have to repeat the experience without the `'s/\./_/g' | awk '{gsub("___","\t",$0); print;}'` section, and then manually separate the GCA... section from "... */100.00%". I have 61 clusters, and the method I used took a very long time.

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem. Kindly do edit your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F"[> ]" '
BEGIN{
  OFS="_"
}
/^>/{
  close(out_file)
  out_file=$2 OFS $3".txt"
  next
}
{
  match($0,/>[^ ]*/)
  print substr($0,RSTART+1) > (out_file)
}'  Input_file
```

This will print lines in output files which will print lines starting from `>` till first space comes. In case you want to print  everything in output files starting from `>` to till end of line then change from `/>[^ ]/*` to `/^.*/` in above code's `match` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '/^>/ {close(file); file=substr($0,2) ".txt"; gsub(" ","_",file); next}
       file {$1=$2=""; $0=$0; $1=$1; print > file}' file
```